# Get a dom inside a frame

Tags: javascript, html, dom, firefox-addon, frame

For a browser extension, I am trying to access an element that is inside a frame, but it seems like I can't find the frame.

I tried the following

```
var frame = parent.frames["Interface"];

var frame = window.frames["Interface"];
```

Both return `undefined` and I basically just don't understand how (if?) I can access this element, provided the information bellow:

The "achitecture" of the document is the following:

[image]

I need to access an element, using its ID, within the frame "Interface" that is somewhere in the body outlined in the image.

When I print the `window` variable, I get the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exploring the winfow object, (thank you console.log), I fanally managed to find:

`window[0].frames` returns directly the "Interface" frame. I can then access the element with `getElementById`

```
var frame = window[0].frames;

var element= frame.document.getElementById("element");
```